# longest decreasing sequence of elements in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find the longest decreasing sequence of elements of a matrix of size n x n where sequence

> S = (mi1j1, mi2j2, · · · , mikjk)

such
that

> ir < ir+1, jr < jr+1, and mirjr > mir+1jr+1 for all 1 ≤ r < k

. I am not being able to think of how to approach the problem . I need to apply dynamic programming to it.
 Can anybody give me a hint on how should I approach this problem. (Since this is my HW so plz dont give exact solution. I am looking for reading material using which I can understand this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a dynamic programming solution is rather simple and I don't think that it requires any additional reading. Let's assume that f(i, j) is the lenght of the longest decreasing sequence that ends in (i, j) element. If the values of f are computed for all i, j such that i < ik and j < jk, it is easy to compute f(ik, jk). So it is possible to compute the answer iteratively(in the increasing order of i and j).

Answer (score 0):

Let mi,j=INF-mi,j, where INF - very big number:), then task is to find longest increasing sequence, read that blog http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1412